# How are high voltage ultrasounds kept safe?

Tags: ultrasound

EDITED question to be more useful. I don't understand why driving piezo ultrasound at 100V isn't a huge safety hazard. I have seen lab settings where the lead wires are attached to a device on skin. (I am clearly not in the field, but have need to know this)

Comment: they are insulating ceramics so they need HVAC  to resonate (Piezo effect)  some up to 5MHz

Comment: Because piezos will produce that much voltage when deformed by the same amount a pulser needs them to. Two way street like a motor and a generatpr being the same thing but used opposite ways.

Comment: If you mean something like a piezo, it is not that they will not work at lower voltage, they just won't be very loud.  They essentially only draw power and do work while the voltage is *changing*, so to get more change at the same frequency you need more voltage.  Needless to say synthesized **100v signals have no place in a beginner project** - setting aside functionality, safety argues for picking a different project or using a prebuilt encapsulated solution.

Comment: ok. is there safety implications then for testing new US devices at that voltage? im reading a research paper on wearable thick film US device that has wire leads for testing

Comment: The danger is in an amplifier type driver circuit and its DC supply rails, especially if misconfigured.  Something task-dependent using inductive kick where the high voltage is a result of the pulsing itself could in some cases be less of an issue than a DC rail + amplifier type of universal solution designed to produce clean waveforms, but it really depends on the details.

Comment: the research paper was focused on a new piezo that was literally attached to skin, and just used an Olympus 5077 to drive the piezos via an ACF cable. whatever is coming out of Olympus must not be dangerous

Comment: A PZT being driven from  human-movement loads will never cause problems with safety. People just don't provide the power, and PZTs are too inefficient, to cause injury.  As to your original question, PZTs work by deforming the molecular structure of the ceramic. This requires large electric fields which in turn means large voltage swings.

Comment: Maybe you could link the particular paper and/or provide the diagram of the application that you are questioning? Danger comes from possible paths of current, not (directly) from some particular potential near skin. For example, a thickness mode disk might have 100V across it, but if the supply is galvanically isolated and only one side touches the skin, no current can flow. Needless to say, if you need to ask about that kind of thing, you shouldn't be physically tinkering with this stuff.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany YES! go to https://sci-hub.tw/ (thanks russia) and search for "Monitoring of the central blood pressure waveform via a conformal ultrasonic device". (fill in the captcha). i am not tinkering, just doing feasibility studies. more info in supplementary info https://www.nature.com/articles/s41551-018-0287-x

Answer (score 2):

The paper you reference appears to show a transducer made with something like flex-PC technology, plus some piezo material. The substrate (silicone?) and the coverlay are insulators and should prevent current from flowing through the skin. The consequences of any defects in the insulator would have to be evaluated by a qualified person (which, in this field, I definitely am not), but without a path through the heart localized tissue damage would probably be the worst of it. A mil (25um) of polyimide has a breakdown voltage of 7700V typically, for example.

(image from the paper doi:10.1038/s41551-018-0287-x)

[image]